# Converting a String variable in to Resource variable in PHP

Tags: php, smarty

I have a resource variable in `php` and I pass It to other `php` page using `Smarty` assignments but when I retrieve this resource variable on other `php` pages it becomes `string` type Variable. How can I convert it back to Resource variable ?
Its Like This:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbconfig['db_hostname'],$dbconfig['db_username'],$dbconfig['db_password']);
$smarty->assign("DBCONNNAME",  $conn);
```

Comment: That's not how you would use Smarty. What's the resource you're trying to pass and why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're clearly doing something wrong here. Smarty is a templating engine. If you need to use the database connection is Smarty, you would be breaking the whole concept of separating the logic of the application and the template/view.

Instead of passing the database connection resource to a Smarty template, do everything you need to do (e.g. fetching rows from the database tables) in the PHP script and then assign the data that you retrieve from the database to the Smarty template and display it.